# Image smoothing

Tags: raster, r

I have 9 layer stacked DEM raster image in .tif format. I would like to smooth the image using `focal()` function in `raster` package in R.

```
img <- brick("/stack.tif")
img <- focal(img, w=matrix(1,4,4), fun=modal)
```

Getting this error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘focal’ for signature ‘"RasterBrick"’
```

Comment: You can't run `focal` over anything with more than one band. You have 9 bands. Do you want to run that operation on each band separately? Loop over the bands?

Comment: Do you want to reduce the multiple layers to one getting the mode for each pixel from the "above" or do you want to have a focal image for every single layer?